# Bootstrap custom-checkbox не сохраняет выбор

Tags: bootstrap

Создал такой переключатель в AdminLTE 3:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
```

Но при его переключении ничего не происходит. При включении переключателя не добавляется атрибут checked для input, при его выключении этот атрибут не исчезает если был добавлен в input вручную. Как сделать чтобы состояние переключателя синхронизировалось с атрибутом checked input поля для отправки значения вместе с формой?

Воспроизводится в Chrome 91 и Firefox во всех примерах использования этого элемента, например [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_custom_switch&stacked=h)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось довольно просто. Атрибут checked не должен меняться при включении или выключении checkbox или этого переключателя. Если переключатель выключен, то в форму просто ничего не передается.